# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. --> MyContract.sol:9:27: | 9 | function get() public views returns(string) { | ^^^^^

Tags: solidity, remix

i am new to solidity....i was following a tutorial but this error DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. --> MyContract.sol:9:27: | 9 | function get() public views returns(string) { | ^^^^^

the code i tried to compile is

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;


contract MyContract {

string value;


function get() public views returns(string) {
    
     return value;
}


}
```

can someone tell me why
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Beside of typo in function modifier `view` you'll require data location provided for string return type

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;


contract MyContract {

    string value;
    
    function get() public view returns(string memory) {
        return value;
    }
}
```